# Java Vectors: how to quickly "symmetrify" a large chunk of a huge sparse matrix

Tags: java, arrays, performance, memory-management, matrix

I have a huge sparse matrix (about 500K x 500K entries, with approximately 1% of the values being non-zero.

I'm using @mikera's Vectorz library.

t is a `SparseRowMatrix` composed of `SparseIndexedVector` rows.

For this chunk of the matrix, I am computing weights for (i,j) where j>i, putting them into an array of double, then creating the `SparseIndexedVector` for the row from that array.  I was trying to cache the weights so that for the parts of the row where `j<i`, I could look up the previously computed value for (j,i) and put that value in for (i,j), but that took too much memory.  So I am now trying to basically just compute and fill in the upper triangle for that chunk of the matrix, and then "symmetrify" it later.  The chunk is from `n1` x `n1` to `n2` x `n2` (where `n2 - n1 =~ 100K`).

Conceptually, this is what I need to do:

```
    for (int i = n1; i < n2; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n2; j++) {
            double w = t.get(i, j);
            if (w > 0) {
                t.set(j, i, w);
            }
        }
    }
```

But the "random access" `get` and `set` operations are quite slow.  I assume `unsafeGet` would be faster.

Would it improve my performance to do the `j`-loop as my outer loop and convert the row back to a double array, then add elements and then create a new SparseIndexedVector from that array and `replaceRow` it back in?  Something like:

```
for (j = n1 + 1; j < n2; j++) {
    double[] jRowData = t.getRow(j).asDoubleArray();
    for (i = 1; i < j-1; i++) {
        double w = t.unsafeGet(i,j);
        if (w > 0) {
            jRowData[i] = w;
        }
     }
     SparseIndexedVector jRowVector = SparseIndexedVector.createLength(n);
     jRowVector.setElements(jRowData);         
     t.replaceRow(j, jRowVector);
}
```

Would something like that likely be more efficient?  (I haven't tried it yet, as testing things on such large arrays takes a long time, so I'm trying to get an idea of what is "likely" to work well first.  I've tried various incarnations on a smaller array (1K x 1K), but I've found that what is faster on a small array is not necessarily the same as what is faster on a large array.)

Is there another approach I should take instead?

Also, since memory is also a large concern for me, would it be helpful at the end of the outer loop to release the array memory explicitly?  Can I do that by adding `jRowData = null;`?  I assume that would save time on GC but I'm not all that clear on how memory management works in Java (7 if it matters).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is symmetric if m[x,y] is equal to m[y,x] for all x and y, so if you know that the matrix must be symmetric, storing both m[x,y] and m[y,x] is redundant.

You can avoid storing both by rearranging the inputs if they meet a certain condition:

```
void set(int row, int col, double value) {

    if(col < row) {
       //call set again with transposed col/row
       return set(col, row, value);

    //we now know that we're in the top half of the matrix, proceed like normal
    ...
}
```

Do something similar for the get method:

```
double get(int row, int col) {

    if(col < row) {
       //call get again with transposed col/row
       return get(col, row);

    //we now know that we're in the top half of the matrix, proceed like normal
    ...
    return value;
}
```

This technique will allow you to both avoid storing redundant values, and force the matrix to be symmetric without having to do any extra processing.

Comment: The entire matrix isn't symmetric, just little blocks of it.  Yes, I could hack some get/set methods that know about the symmetric regions, but I also need to use matrix multiplication on this matrix once it's filled, and I think I would lose out on some efficiencies built into the matrix multiplication methods.

Comment: I think you must mean `return get(row, col);` at the end of your modified `get` method

Comment: @PurpleVermont the idea is to transpose the column and row. You could replace it with code to swap col and row.

Comment: The problem is that overriding get and set doesn't "cover" me.  If the methods I call on my matrix use "getRow" instead, for example, it won't get the right data if I don't actually fill the data into the rows.

Answer (score 0):

The [la4j](http://la4j.org) library guarantees `O(log n)` (where the `n` is a dimension) performance for both `get/set` operations on sparse matrices like `CRSMatrix` or `CCSMatrix`. You can perform a small experiment - just compile your code from *conceptual* box and run it with la4j:

```
for (int i = n1; i < n2; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n2; j++) {
        double w = t.get(i, j);
        if (w > 0) {
            t.set(j, i, w);
        }
    }
}
```

You said you have to handle 500K x 500K matrices. For this size you can expect `log_2(500 000) ~ 18` internal binary search iterations will be performed at each call to `get/set` operations.

Just think about 18 loop iterations on a moderl JVM and modern CPU.

Hope this helps. Have fun.

Comment: I actaully switched form la4j to vectorz because vectorz gave me better performance for other parts of my algorithm.